# Don't get why argument of power sets being uncountable works

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Statement: $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable.

Proof by contradiction: 
Assume $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is countable.
Let $A_{i} \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. Now define a set $B = \{i\in A: i \notin A_{i}\}$. However, $B \subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, which means $B = A_{j}$ for some j.

This is a contradiction.

If $j \in B = A_{j}$, then $j \notin B$ by definition of set B.

If $j \notin B = A_{j}$, then $j \in B$ by definition of set B.

Therefore by contradiction, powerset is uncountable.This is the generic proof.

When we say let there be a set $B = \{i\in A: i \notin A_{i}\}$. This set B is an element of power set, but by definition B cannot be in powerset, thus by contradiction power set of A is uncountable.

I understand what is at contradiction, but I don't get how we can just assume such a set B exists in the first place to be able to form a contradiction?

Comment: Why would there not be such a set $B$? You don't have to have a function map to every element of its codomain, i.e. $f$ need not be surjective.

Comment: In addition (assuming we already have a set $A$ and a function $f$): Note that the set $B$ can be empty.  Each element $i$ is either in $f(A)$, or not, and we decide to put $i$ in the set $B$ depending on that. So $B$ is just the set of all elements $i$ with that particular property (if no elements have that property then $B$ is the empty set).

Comment: Some context perhaps? What is $A$, is it countable? What is $f$?

Comment: It's a standard (Cantors?) proof in showing powerset is uncountable. I edited to show whole proof.

Comment: @MinYoungKim : Your "proof" never defines $f$.  If I were to guess the context, I would guess taht you have a typo and you really mean $B = \{i \in A: i \notin f(i)\}$. This would make sense and would be useful if we assume existence of a set $A$ and a surjective function $f:A\rightarrow 2^A$.

Comment: http://www.cs.xu.edu/csci250/06s/Theorems/powerSetuncountable.pdf . This is what I was looking at. I guess it's not as explicit about the mapping function f. Is the proof shown in the link specific enough, or too "loose"?

Comment: There is no reason to do this proof on the natural numbers, might as well let $A$ be any set. I note that the notes use $i \notin A_i$ which is essentially the same as my guess $i \notin f(i)$.

Comment: @Michael so what i'm getting is that any element $i $ is either in f(A), or it is not. However, if we group the elements that are not in f(A), it turns out it does belong to f(A), so it's a contradiction?

Comment: With teh fixed context, it is that every element $i$ either satisfies $i \notin f(i)$, or it does not, so the set $B = \{i \in A : i \notin f(i)\}$ makes sense (possibly being empty).  Since $B$ is a subset of $A$, and since $f$ is surjective, there must be an element $a^* \in A$ such that $f(a^*)=B$, and we ask if $a^*\in B$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: You can do this in Zermelo and its extensions because the existence of such a $B$ is an instance of the axiom schema of Separation or Replacement. There are unusual set theories that reject these schemata, and those theories may have $A=\mathcal{P}(A)$, or even $\mathcal{P}(A)\subsetneq A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to think of this more constructively. I claim:

> Any time you give me a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, I can give you a set $A_f\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ with $A\not\in ran(f)$.

This simplifies things by removing the unnecessary contradiction aspect.

So let's prove my claim. Suppose you give me an $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. I'll build my set $A$ as follows: it's just the set of $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $i\not\in f(i).$ More succinctly, we're defining $A$ by saying $$i\in A\iff i\not\in f(i).$$ Note that **you've already supplied the relevant function** - there's no circularity here, since the definition of $A$ comes *after* you've already provided your $f$.

It's clear that *if $A$ is a set* then $A\not\in ran(f)$. So we only have one question: why is this a valid definition of a set?

Well, ultimately this will come down to the specific axiomatic framework you're using, but the idea in [the usual set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) is that "$i\not\in f(i)$" is a *well-formed statement* which is either true or false for each specific $i\in \mathbb{N}$. For example, if your particular $f$ has $$f(7)=\{2,4,6,8,10,...\},$$ then we'd have $7\in A$ since $7\not\in\{2,4,6,8,10,...\}$.

And now we go to our precise axiomatic system. [One of the ways we build sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) is via formulas: given a set $A$ and a property $p$, we can form the set $\{x\in A: x$ has property $p\}$. Here our property $p$ is "is not an element of $f$ applied to it."

Does this mean you can block Cantor's argument if you weaken your axioms enough? Well, sure, practically *anything* can be blocked if you are willing to throw away axioms willy-nilly. But the definition of $A$ here is so simple that (so far) there isn't any known useful set theory which is able to construct powersets but can't prove that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable.

Comment: "Note that you've already supplied the relevant function - there's no circularity here, since the definition of  comes after you've already provided your ." This is the kind of explanation I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplified proof is this: Let $A$ be any nonempty set.  Let $f:A\rightarrow 2^A$ be a function.  Assume $f$ is surjective (we reach a contradiction).  Define $$B = \{i \in A : i \notin f(i)\}$$ 
Since $B$ is a (possibly empty) subset of $A$, by surjectiveness there must be an element $a^* \in A$ such that $f(a^*)=B$.  Is $a^* \in B$?  Both "yes" and "no" lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Note that $A$ and $f$ are already defined, and so the set $B$ makes sense: We simply test every element $i$ to find out if $i \notin f(i)$, and based on this we decide whether or not $i$ is included in $B$.

Comment: Credit where due, of course. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem